# Re-direct all referral id url's?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Users are provided with unique URL's, ie: example.com/AQ4ILB9
AQ4ILB9 being the referral code

I would still like to display index.php from that URL as above (or any referral URL), however keep the URL in the browser as the referral url (example.com/AQ4ILB9)

How can I do this and is htaccess the best method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?_url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Then `$_GET['_url']` will hold `AQ4ILB9` in `index.php`.

I think htaccess is the easiest way and most maintainable way. Easy to move around without reconfiguring everything again if you have to change servers, and easy to version control if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason now though, my css isn't displaying? :/

Comment: How can I also include a non-www 301 to the www version, no matter of with index.php at the end or not.. I always want it displayed in the browser as http : // www.example.com / (without the spaces) and if with the code, "/AQ4ILB9" at the end of it. Thank you!